# Create array from ajax call

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm having trouble getting this into the right format.

I have this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'att_count_2.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: allvars[0],
            success: function(data) {

              var export_data = [];
              $('#export').click(function() {
                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                 var export_data = value.exuid; 
                 console.log(export_data);
                 //var final_one = export_data.join(",")

                }); 
        });
```

The console.log give me one line each for the `exuid`s that match my criteria. Like this:

```
9a2234e4-cfc8-47da-b03a-0ed52e80f0e2  
4d06e206-261b-4774-b553-6785f13cd64e  
1ec1c7ea-85f4-4ba4-ab70-bf1e56cf9bd2
```

This works great. However, what I need is this:

```
[9a2234e4-cfc8-47da-b03a-0ed52e80f0e2,4d06e206-261b-4774-b553-6785f13cd64e,1ec1c7ea-85f4-4ba4-ab70-bf1e56cf9bd2]
```

If I uncomment out the `join` statement I have above, it throws an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented out code is trying to invoke a `join` method on a `string` object which does not exist (or rather is `undefined`) hence the error message you are receiving.

When trying to *append* data onto an array you would need to use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like so,

```
success: function(data) {
          ...
          var export_data = [];
          $('#export').click(function() {
             $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                export_data.push(value.exuid);
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect, but I realize now that I need this format:

`[["q9a2234e4-cfc8-47da-b03a-0ed52e80f0e2"], ["4d06e206-261b-4774-b553-6785f13cd64e "]]`

How can I change your code to get this?

Comment: Nevermind...got it! Changed to: `export_data.push([value.exuid]);`

Comment: @jonmrich You're welcome and glad to hear that you had figured it out yourself, that's generally the best way that I learn.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` method to get the property from each item into a new array:

```
$('#export').click(function() {
  var final_one = $.map(data, function (value) {
    return value.exuid;
  });
  // use final_one
});
```

Answer (score 1):

by saying

```
var export_data = value.exuid;
```

you're reassigning your export_data array every time. 
What you want to do is add elements to the export_data array like this:

```
export_data.push(value.exuid);
```